# Cannot map <C-h>, and not sure why

Tags: neovim

I'm remapping `<C-[hjkl]>` to be used for navigating between window splits. `<C-[jkl]>` are all working as expected. `<C-h>` is not working, and I cannot figure out why.

Here is how I'm mapping them:

```
:nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
:nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
:nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
:nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

When I run `verbose nnoremap <C-h>` I see

```
n  <C-H>       * <C-W>h                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        Last set from ~/.nvimrc
```

**EDIT**:  Turns out this issue is specific to Neovim.  If you come across this question and are working with vim, it won't apply to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably this [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/2048). You can try following

> Set `kbs=\177` in your terminal's terminfo/termcap:
>
> ```
> infocmp $TERM | sed 's/kbs=^[hH]/kbs=\\177/' > $TERM.ti
> tic $TERM.ti
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/wiki/Troubleshooting#my-ctrl-h-mapping-doesnt-work)